# hiding certain field in form when user posts

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I have a form in my application with "price" field in some categories i don't want that field to appear in the user form. How is it possible to do ?

Comment: Do you want that the price field appears only for products belonging to some categories?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hidden input field to do this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="The value you want">
```

This will still send it's value to the database when submitting, but users can't see it.